# PDF View - How Can I Search Text?

Tags: iphone, pdf

I'm iphone developer and I'm developing pdf reader like iBooks.

By using CoreGraphics Framework I displayed pdf content.

But how can I implement search action and highlight it?

I also saw FastPdfKit and PDFKitten program. But I want the other way.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686924/which-are-the-pdf-operators-needed-to-do-a-search-feature-in-a-pdf-in-iphone-sdk

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335799/is-there-any-framework-to-highlight-text-on-pdf-file-after-rendering-on-the-ipho

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit