# iOS CGPdf highlight text using CGrect

Tags: ios, cgpdfdocument, cgpdf, cgpdfcontext

I am trying to highlight text using rect but the code below:

CGRect originalSize = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pagePDFRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);

return me rect less then I expected or maybe less then I see.

Is there any already made method that highlight text using scanner and CGRect

Comment: Check out PDFKitten.  It helped me quite a lot.  https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten

Comment: @Putz1103 have it got scan with rect features ?

Comment: Yes.  If you went to the link that I posted for you it says `Finally, scan the page and draw the selections.`

Comment: @Putz1103 I just downloaded pdfkitten but it does not work

Comment: It works fine for me.  You asked for ready made solutions, that is one.  I can't help you further than that.

Comment: @Putz1103 yep in any case thank you for comments