# iOS How to get all words coordinates in PDF page

Tags: ios, pdf, nsscanner, cgpdfdocument, cgpdfscanner

I have looked through many tutorials and usually stack users trow links to the pdfkitten, but as I've tested it I have not satisfied with result. So the search does not work with multiply word and etc.

So what I am looking for I need to get all words from the pdf page and highlight it if the words cross some rectangle.

Comment: Could you ever found a solution to this? If yes, please add it as an answer so it can be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used PDFKitten for the same.

- What I did was while scanning the PDF - Identify the words separated
  by spaces.
- Save the RenderingState(Model in PDFKitten code)word is
  encountered save that word in a model with it's current
  RenderingState (Model in PDFKitten code) which will be initial state.
  When the complete word is found(space separated) again save the
  current RenderingState as final state.
- The code for converting RenderingState to actual view's frame using 
  above initial state and final state, is present in PDFKitten. You can
  refer to that code.
- apply current media box transform to frame.
- And finally don't forget
  to convert resulted frame into user's co-ordinate system. Otherwise
  you will observe the reverse effect.

Comment: However there is problem in CMap parsing of PDFKitten. It throws away many mapping. You may want to fix that first so that you will have correct character mapping.

Comment: Hi Swaroop, can you please share the code which you have explained here?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Its a commercial app, so can't share the code.